# How do you populate NFT (images) in-game?

Tags: nft, decentralized-applications, webapp

Sushibyte (and other game projects) has users input their wallet and then populates specific NFT's as playable images.

Could someone walk me through the logic that verifies the desired policy ID and pulls the NFT's image onto the application?

Comment: For the Dapp connector method, how can we convert the getUxto() method to something readable? i.e. How can we convert the given cbor type to addresses. Would have made this a comment but don't have the rep for it

Answer (score 1):

2 ways:

- Blockfrost API (Easy): Query a wallet's address UTXOs. If an NFT is owned by the wallet you can find it here.

[https://docs.blockfrost.io/#tag/Cardano-Addresses/paths/~1addresses~1{address}~1utxos/get](https://docs.blockfrost.io/#tag/Cardano-Addresses/paths/%7E1addresses%7E1%7Baddress%7D%7E1utxos/get)

- Dapp Connector: Ask a User to connect their wallet to your website and use the wallet's getBalance() api to get all UTXOs from the wallets.

https://github.com/cardano-foundation/CIPs/blob/e8f56d95993474a24795c834d33026b6449e1d99/CIP-0030/README.md#apigetbalance-promisecborvalue